# TypeError: missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, ооп, классы

Начинаю учить ООП.Код:

```
class d():
    atribute = 8
    def __init__(self):
        self.atr = 42
    def i(self):
        print(self.atr)
    def static():
        print(d.atribute)
    @static
if __name__ == "__main__":
    d.static()
    obj = d()
    d.i()
    obj.static()
```

Ошибка:TypeError:  I missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: Ваш код имеет синтаксическую ошибку и запускаться не должен в принципе — `@static` болтается где попало и ничего не декорирует

Answer (score 1):

```
"""
Демонстрация
"""
class Demo(object):
    """
    Демонстрационный класс
    """
    atribute = 8

    def __init__(self, init_data=42):
        """
        Конструктор
        :param init_data: Парметр инициализации. Дефолт - 42
        """
        self.atr = init_data

    def i(self):
        """
        Что то там поделали
        :return:
        """
        print(self.atr)

    @staticmethod
    def static():
        """
        Еще что то там поделали
        :return:
        """
        print(Demo.atribute)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Demo.static()   # Статический мтод вызвали
    obj = Demo()    # Инициализировали с дефолтными параметрами
    obj.i()         # Вызвали обычный метод
    obj.static()    # Вызвали статический
    obj3 = Demo(5)  # Воспользовались параметрическим конструктором
    obj3.i()        # Вызвали обычный метод
    obj1 = Demo  # Просто присвоили (так полагаю указатель)
    obj1.static()  # Статический метод вызвали
```

И перед тем как выкладывать синтаксис проверяйте. Pylint в помощь

Comment: Спасибо,окей,надо будет посмотреть что за сайт

Comment: Taras PyLint - это статистический анализатор кода. Проверяет по стандарту кодирования, как пример PEP8. И еще с языком определитесь - если такие вопросы задаете то С++ точно не ваш язык.

Comment: Только 3 месяц в программировании.Насчёт c++ , он вообще не для новичков.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать декоратор `@staticmethod`, а чтобы получить атрибуты класса, нужно использовать декоратор `@classmethod`.

Пример:

```
In [64]: class StackOverflow:
    ...:     class_attr = 1337
    ...:
    ...:     def __init__(self, name):
    ...:         self.name = name
    ...:
    ...:     @staticmethod
    ...:     def static_func():
    ...:         return 'hello world'
    ...:
    ...:     @classmethod
    ...:     def class_method_func(cls):
    ...:         return cls.class_attr
    ...:

In [65]: StackOverflow.static_func()
Out[65]: 'hello world'

In [66]: StackOverflow.class_method_func()
Out[66]: 1337
```

Comment: Спасибо,но я так и не понял,где в коде используется staticmethod and classmethod

Comment: @Taras `@staticmethod` когда в функция не нужно передавать экземпляр, а `@classmethod` когда взаимодействие идёт с атрибутами класса.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо

Comment: @Taras, вам пока не нужно использовать ни то ни другое. Сначала разберитесь с основами. `@staticmethod` и `@classmethod` - это довольно специфичные виды методов, которые могут на практике вам понадобиться не скоро.

Comment: Да,уже понял,только осталось найти,где и как учить этот ООП.Вообще начальных курсов нету.

Comment: @Taras думаю это для Вас https://wombat.org.ua/AByteOfPython/object_oriented_programming.html

Answer (score 0):

```
class CamelCase(object):
    atribute = 8

    def __init__(self):
        self.atr = 42

    def i(self): # Этот метод работает только у экземпляра класса (obj)
        print(self.atr)

    @staticmethod # Этот метод работает и БЕЗ экземпляра (obj)
    def static():
        print(CamelCase.atribute)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    CamelCase.static()
    obj = CamelCase()
    obj.i() # Здесь была ошибка, потому что вызывали метод не у экземпляра класса CamelCase
    obj.static()
```

Класс `CamelCase` создан с `object`, потому что версия *Python* у меня 3.